# Subtrahendum/Subtrahenda

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, latin, neologisms

We are familiar with *addendum* (and *addenda*), which we take directly from Latin to mean

- "something (or things) added"

This is used especially in regard to written work such as books.

Today I was writing/editing a summary of a meeting I had attended,  and gave a draft of the summary to one senior colleague (who also had attended the meeting) for him to review, before I send it out to a larger audience.

He pointed out several items (small sections)  in the summary, which actually were discussed at the meeting, but which he felt it would be ill-advised to publish, for office-political reasons.

I edited the summary, removing those parts and setting them aside in a separate file.  It made sense to me to title that file *Subtrahenda*, on the arithmetical model:

Addend* + Addend = Sum

Minuend – Subtrahend = Difference

I then used an online dictionary metasearch  and found that *subtrahendum* apparently does not appear in any of the "usual" dictionaries. But it does appear in the Urban Dictionary, in the sense I expected.

http://ru.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=subtrahendum

However, that definition mentions "a list", which, it serms to me, would better be described as *subtrahenda* (from the latin plural, like *agenda* and *addenda*).

I am well aware of *redaction*, but my understanding is that this refers to striking of text after a document was printed. (An aside: I learned today that many of Secretary Hillary Clinton's email messages were just released, and one part of one of them was redacted because it was retroactively declared  "classified" by the FBI, though that information was not "classified" at the time it was sent. So the topic seems timely, although her case differs from mine; hers seems clearly about *redaction*.)

I realize that the process of removing text *before* publication (by the author( is a kind of_prior (self) censorship_, but I am not looking for a word for the process, but rather for the part that was removed and set aside.

So my question is this: is there an existing word that means exactly that—the portion that is intentionally removed from a document (by the author) before its publication, *and saved as a separate smaller document*?  Or should I use the neologism **subtrahendum**, or my variant of it **subtrahenda**?

*(sometimes called the *augend*)

Comment: Why are you even keeping this file if your coworker believes that publishing it would be a bad idea?

Comment: If it belongs with the other document. is it a codicil?

Comment: @SomethingDark: CYA. And I'm a packrat. And it might come in handy if later if the politics change.

Comment: @Hugh: Well, I suppose that if in future I chose to make it an addendum, it would become a codicil. But not now, while it's still a subtrahendum.

Comment: I would call the text in question an *archived excision* from the main document.

Comment: Worth noting that your UD link has just 1 definition; with 0 upvotes and 8 downvotes.

Comment: Neologisms work best when their meaning is apparant. 'Cross-cuisine' isn't defined anywhere, but if someone uses the term, it is pretty easy to guess what they mean. I'm not sure the same can be said about `subtrahendum`, even as jargon.

Comment: @Tushar Raj: Indeed, that's the catch. Few people were taught, and fewer remember, the "arithmetic" nomenclature. And four syllables just isn't as catchy as three. (agenda, addenda). Of course, I'm an incorrigible sesquipedalian, so multisyllabics  exhilarate rather than discombobulate me. As for UD, I wouldn't consider that as justification (whether upvoted or downvoted) but I mentioned it because that was the only dictionary where I found the word. So at least I know I wasn't the first to think of it. Just showing my research.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Wasn't attempting to discredit your research, just pointing out the facts. Additionally, you might be the "incorrigible sesquipedalian", but you need to consider if your audiences are.

Comment: That's the interesting thing. There is no audience. This is only for my own satisfaction in labeling it appropriately. In fact, maybe a filename that makes perfect sense to but is gobbledegook to anyone else is exactly what I need. In which case I should close my own question. But I'll wait a bit longer to see if any more attractive alternatives are offered.

Comment: @Eric Kowal: nice. I would consider that. It's logical, understandable, and only 4 characters longer than subtrahendum.

Comment: Your neologism would be perfectly transparent to me, and I would understand it immediately to mean “things that are to be subtracted”. As Stoney says, though, that's only what the classified bits are while they're still in the original document; once the subtrahenda have been subtracted, they become subtracta.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet:  Point taken.  So the neologism should be _subtracta_ (or perhaps _subtractum_ if we consider any amount of text to be singular).  I say "neologism" because  _subtracta_ doesn't seem to be in the dictionaries either.  I found it only as a part of _Dioryctria Subtracta_, the scientific name for _snout moth_, and as the name of a child character in a math story problem at the Houston Children's Museum website. (Her dog's name is Minus.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *-end-* morpheme in *subtrahendum, -a* signifies in Latin a *gerundive*: a verbform designating things ***to be*** *VERBen*. *Corrigenda* is the title of a list of things which you are to correct, presumably by paging through the text, striking the mistakes and writing in the corrections. *Agenda*, likewise, designates things to be done, in the vague future or on a specific occasion. Cato the Censor was famous for urging on all occasions *Carthago delenda est*, "Carthage must be destroyed".

Your file, however, contains a number of items which ***have been*** removed; for these you want a past/passive participle form: *subtracta* or *redacta* or *deleta*.

In ordinary English usage, however, where we have naturalized verbs derived from the passive participle, we use the nominal derivative in *-(t)ion*: *subtractions*, *redactions*, *deletions*.

Comment: A gerundive is also known as a __future passive participle__.

Comment: @Mitch I still can't shake off 7th grade Latin. A better name, though I'd be happier calling it something like an unfulfilled passive ppl, since it represents something which at reference time ought to be done or is expected to be done.

Comment: Thanks, StoneyB; that was elucidating as to the Latin conjugations.  However, I find that in the English dictionaries I consult, _subtraction_ is always defined as a process, or an operation, or an instance of such a process/operation—never as _the thing subtracted_. Odd, perhaps, since one can, for example, build _an addition_ on a house. But I'm afraid nobody would consider _subtraction_ in the sense I need, as that's not in the dictionary. It seems I would be inventing a new meaning for _subtraction_.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Not inventing a new meaning--employing an everyday extension of sense, which does not appear in the dictionary simply because nobody has ever needed it. Dictionaries don't authorize meanings, they record them. And apparently you need not worry about what the word means to anybody but yourself! ... But you can still use the Latin pappl *subtracta* -- though I would incline more toward ***extracta*** -- which you can with plenty of precedent English as either  *extractions* or *extracts*.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Incidentally, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=W3ZgSxuGwVEC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=%22his+subtractions%22&source=bl&ots=ZLeGYrpNeF&sig=G3YRcq_1qzznYT_xjBoHZrGBzRQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tBFjVcnGM8P5yQSQtIKADw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22his%20subtractions%22&f=false) is an instance of *subtraction* used in a scholarly work in the sense I put forward.

Comment: Great! Now we're getting somewhere. As for _extract_, I already use that for portions **not** removed, which I **do** publish. For example, someone might request a file containing only a certain chapter or section of a larger document. I can produce the "extract" without affecting the larger document. Do you think this is appropriate usage of _extract_?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Then you might see *extractions* as properly differenced from *extracts*.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting concept, but your definition of addendum is flawed.  *Addendum* could actually refer to your extra document as well, since it contains stuff that isn't in the original; it *adds* to it.  Your neologism seems to me to mean stuff that shouldn't be in the final document (yet exists there already).

Why not simply call it *redactions*?  Or label it "company internal"?

While it's fun to make up new words, we should probably do so only when existing words do not convey the entire sense.

Also somewhat relevant – the government uses the term *sanitized* to refer to a document that may have once contained classified information that has since been redacted or otherwise removed.  Source documents may also be [portion-marked](http://www.archives.gov/isoo/training/portion-marking.pdf), indicating which lines are unclassified and which are classified; for instance an overall SECRET document might have sections that are UNCLASSIFIED, which would receive a "(U)" at the beginning of that section.  All other sections would have "(S)" prepended.

Comment: The original draft, or minuend, did contain this text. But that minuend  version no longer exists (provided I make sure not to leave any "tracked changes" in the edited Word doc!) The subtrahend (removed content) and the difference (edited publishable document) are all that exist.  Interesting discussion of how the government does it; I'm not that sophisticated.